# phonegap dynamic javascript button

Tags: javascript, cordova

Learning how to use Phonegap to create an Android application I am still experimenting with the fundamentals of HTML and JavaScript. Trying to add a button, I must have done something fundamentally wrong...

this is my body element:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="divContent">   
        <p id="content"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To start with I have some basic functionaloty. I have a databasequery (it works) and the result should produce some text and a button:

```
if(results.rows.item(0).c == 0){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=
        "You don't have any service items ....etc";
    var btn = document.createElement("newItem");
    btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
    btn.setAttribute("value", "AAARGH!");
    btn.setAttribute("name", "btnNew");
    document.getElementById("divContent").appendChild(btn);
}
```

The text is displayed, the button is not and I cannot understand why. From what I have read this is the way to create a button with JavaScript.

Full source is available here: http://code.google.com/p/easy-service/source/browse/trunk/EasyService-Common/app/app.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `button` node like this:

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
```

The parameter you're passing in is the type of element-- in this case, we want an `input` element.